# Suppose that $f: R \to R: f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is invertible, then find all possible values of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{f^{-1}(x)}$

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

Suppose that $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is given by $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$ is invertible, then find all possible values of $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{f^{-1}(x)}$

My attempt

To find the possible values of the integral $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{f^{-1}(x)}$, where $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is an invertible function, we can use the concept of integration by substitution.

Let $y = f(x)$ and $u = f^{-1}(x)$. Then, $u = f^{-1}(x) \iff x = f(u)$. Now, we have:

$$\frac{dx}{du} = \frac{d}{du}(f(u))$$

By the inverse function theorem, since $f$ is invertible, $\frac{dx}{du}$ is never equal to zero, so we can write:

$$dx = \frac{dx}{du} du = \frac{1}{f'(u)} du$$

$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{dx}{f^{-1}(x)} = \int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{u} \cdot \frac{1}{f'(u)} du$$

Comment: Why do you have $dx/du = 1/f’(u)$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Make sure to check your formatting when you post. As it was before, it was difficult to read, so it was unlikely to get a good response.

Comment: You also certainly do not mean to write $\int_{\Bbb R}$.